# How to start a service in a WSL-based Fedora?

Tags: fedora, services, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a Fedora 33 under Windows Subsystem for Linux 2.

I want to run sshd. For that I tried

```
$ sudo systemctl start sshd
```

but I got the error message

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate
```

Searching for this error message I have found

https://linuxhandbook.com/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd/

which suggested to use the service command in this case. I tried but it said

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start sshd.service
```

so I got the same error.

What can I do on my WSL2 based Fedora 33?

UPDATE: I have installed Fedora onto WSL using a cloud image and the wsl command, described here:

https://fedoramagazine.org/wsl-fedora-33/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use fedora 35, but this probably works with other fedora versions too.
Like NotTheDr01ds said , fedora doesn't support `service start sshd`.
So you can run sshd manually by the command `nohup /usr/sbin/sshd -D > sshd.log 2>&1 &`.
Or you will need to make systemd work for wsl.
Since genie supports fedora, so you can try to use it to make systemd work.
Here is the project url: https://github.com/arkane-systems/genie

1. you can download the rpm package, from this page: https://github.com/arkane-systems/genie/releases
2. install the genie-*.x86_64.rpm with the command `dnf install`
3. use genie with the command `genie -s`
4. use systemctl to start sshd `systemctl start sshd`

You may meet the error `Transport endpoint is not connected` on the fourth step. This is caused by a known issue of wsl ldconfig.

Follow these instructions to fix it:
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5548#issuecomment-990521993
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5548#issuecomment-912495487

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention how you installed it, but I assume something like the instructions [here](https://dev.to/bowmanjd/install-fedora-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-4b26).  I've never done much with Fedora, so I decided to load up a quick chroot instance of it with [Fedora-Container-Base](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=26387) using a combination of the instructions above along with [some chroot specific info](https://nmilosev.svbtle.com/quick-and-easy-fedora-minimal-chroot).

It appears to me that Fedora is "all-in" on `systemd`, perhaps more so than most other distributions I've seen.  For instance, Ubuntu will still let you use the `service` command, but as you saw Fedora redirects it to `systemd` anyway.  There's not even a init script for `ssh` to be found under Fedora - It's all `systemd` service files.

[This blog post](https://dev.to/bowmanjd/you-probably-don-t-need-systemd-on-wsl-windows-subsystem-for-linux-49gn) seems to back that up, using Fedora as an example.  It has a number of good suggestions for most *other* services:

- Look at the Dockerfiles for services that you want to run to see how they start and stop the service
- Just use Docker or podman containers anyway.

While good suggestions, they aren't quite as useful for `sshd` in my opinion.

So I'll add my own suggestion -- Look at `systemd` files to see the steps they take to configure and launch (and stop/restart) a service.

For `sshd` under Fedora, the `systemd` service (`usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service`) has dependencies which detect whether or not the host keys have been generated, and do so if they aren't present (e.g. immediately after install).  *(I think -- I can't claim to be a guru at reading `systemd` services.)*

So you'll need to do that step manually for starters (if you haven't already):

```
/usr/libexec/openssh/sshd-keygen ecdsa
/usr/libexec/openssh/sshd-keygen rsa
/usr/libexec/openssh/sshd-keygen ed25519
```

Personal recommendation/bonus tip -- Change the sshd port to something besides 22.  Install [Windows OpenSSH Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse) on the Windows host, which will allow you to easily proxy to any WSL instance on the host.

Then, just start the service manually, using the same command that `systemd` uses (see the aforementioned `.service` file):

```
/usr/sbin/sshd
```

This works for me in the `chroot` Fedora 33 environment.

You may want to consider [supervisord](http://supervisord.org) to manage services in lieu of `systemd` or another PID 1 init.  I've used it under Docker containers, and it worked well for starting/stopping/restarting simple services.  You'll have to roll your own config, but it's straightforward.  And ultimately, it's nice to have that added manageability and recovery if a service stops unexpectedly.

One more note, since you are working with `sshd` under WSL -- Keep in mind that WSL2 instances are always pseudo-NAT'd in a virtual NIC behind the Windows host.  This means that `ssh` (or accessing any service under WSL2) from another computer on the network will require additional effort - See my answers [here](https://superuser.com/a/1618446/1210833) and [here](https://superuser.com/a/1622603/1210833) on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

have a look here:

https://gist.github.com/djfdyuruiry/6720faa3f9fc59bfdf6284ee1f41f950

Greetings
kh